# Does it ever make sense to ensure => file AND ensure => present in init.pp

Tags: puppet

Does it ever make sense to ensure a file is both present and file? Does present imply it's a file or does the `file { '/etc/sendmail':` line define it as a file?

```
class sendmail {

    file { '/etc/sendmail':
      ensure => directory,
      mode => 755
    }

    file { '/etc/sendmail/sendmail.cf':
      ensure  => present,
      ensure  => file,
      backup  => false,
      source => 'puppet:///mymodules/sendmail/sendmail.cf',
    }

    file { '/etc/sendmail/submit.cf':
      ensure  => present,
      ensure  => file,
      backup  => false,
      source => 'puppet:///mymodules/sendmail/submit.cf',
    }

    service {'sendmail': 
      ensure => running
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

`ensure => file` implies `ensure => present`. That is to say the resource should be a file and if is not a file or does not exist, create a file.

`ensure => present` just means that the resource should be a file, directory, or link; if it does not exist, create a file.

So to answer your question: no, it does not make sense to do so.

For more information about `ensure`, check out [the documentation for the file type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-ensure).

Comment: It is also invalid syntax, and semantics. A resource property can only ever have one desired value.